# Call WinSCP to check if files on a host exist or not using a batch file - to run everyday

Tags: batch-file, winscp

[image: with username & password arguments]

I am trying to automate a call to a remote server using WinSCP which is a redundant everyday task. I want the batch file to call remote machine - provide username and password, and later check for if files exist.

So far I am able to start a WinSCP server but still the batch file does not consume username and password - it is still asking for them and/or providing an error regarding too many arguments.

```
chdir /d D:\Program Files\WinSCP\
winscp.com 172.18.186.39 username password
```

[image: simple call prompting]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Your syntax does not even remotely resemble [WinSCP command-line syntax for scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#scripting).*

---

See WinSCP article on [Checking file existence using scripting](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/script_checking_file_existence#scripting):

```
@echo off

set REMOTE_PATH=/home/user/test.txt
winscp.com /command ^
    "open ftp://username:password@ftp.example.com/" ^
    "stat %REMOTE_PATH%" ^
    "exit"

if %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 goto error

echo File %REMOTE_PATH% exists
rem Do something
exit /b 0

:error
echo Error or file %REMOTE_PATH% not exists
exit /b 1
```

The above example is for FTP protocol. You didn't tell use what protocol are you using. If not FTP, you have to change the [`open` command](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_open) accordingly.

You can have [WinSCP GUI generate the `open` command for you](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_generateurl#script).

---

Once you have the batch file ready, use [Windows Scheduler to call it regularly](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_schedule).